# aspx pages downloads after hosting in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, download

We hosted the website in IIS. When we test the home page of our site IIS suddenly offering to download the aspx page instead of rendering .

We hosted the website in IIS 7.0. Website developed with DotnetFramework 4.0.

Please help me in identify the bottom of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to drop into the command prompt and navigate to the folder;

c:\windows\microsoft.NET\Framework\V4.0.30319\

and type the command aspnet_regiis -i

this will configure the IIS server to correctly process the aspx files - not sure why it would work previously and then suddenly stop working,  have you used this explicit version of .NET on this server before?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure it once again. Before that, follow some steps mentioned below:

1. You have to build the web application within your Visual Studio.
2. After successful build,you have to publish the application and save that published copy to specific folder say 'MyPublieshedApp'.
3. Start IIS and add new website. You have to point the folder which contains the published content of your application. In this case the folder should be 'MyPublishedApp'.
4. Set the application pool and set the framework version to ASP.NET 4.0.

5.Then browse one of the page after configuring it into the IIS.

May be this will help you.

Comment: Great to see the reply. I tried the same still file downloads.