# Chrome downloads aspx instead of render, IE works

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Whenever I try visiting an aspx file in Chrome, the browser will download the file.  When I open it in IE, it will actually render that page.  I'm not sure what changed with Chrome as this was working, then half way through the day decided to stop working.

I've tried following [aspnet_regiis -i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043218/aspx-pages-downloads-after-hosting-in-iis) with no success.  Other aspx pages render without issue.  I've been poking around IIS trying to find something that might indicate an incorrect setting, but cannot find anything in particular.

I've done plenty of Googling without any helpful results.

I'm not sure what other information to provide at this time, so please let me know if I can provide any specific information to help.

Comment: Could you compare the response header with others in [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?

Comment: What `Content-Type` is in the response header?

Comment: I don't actually get a request captured in Fiddler when I go to this page.  It just immediately downloads the file.

Comment: From IE:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=xvgx42q02tfkssvevyev1izq; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 24 Feb 2016 14:07:11 GMT
Content-Length: 9652